# Delete a TextTrack from a video

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, media-source, mpeg-dash

Is there a good way to delete a single [`TextTrack`](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#texttrack) added via JavaScript to a HTML5 `<video>` tag? The following code is a simple demo of how to add a track, but I haven't found a good way to remove one:

```
document.querySelector('video#myVideo').addTextTrack(...);
```

Comment: Give this issue a https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1921 a thumb up to raise awareness and make a PR

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no mechanism to remove an added text-track (probably a flaw (?) in the current specification. There is also an `onremovetrack` event but...).

The only thing we can do is to disable or hide it. Make sure you keep a reference to the track:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video#myVideo');
var track = video.addTextTrack("...");
...
track.mode = "showing";  // when cues are added and is ready
```

Then when you no longer need it:

```
track.mode = "disabled"; // or "hidden"
```

(you might get around resetting the src as well, but I haven't tried this..)

Comment: Yeah, that's what I am doing, I just wanted to be sure there's no way around this, for now. The only way to trigger an `onremovetrack` event is by removing the `<track>` node from the video tag, which of course is not possible for "non-DOM" tracks.

Comment: You can add regular tracks with a `<track>` node, and by removing it the related element from the `textTracks` property is immediately removed as well.

Answer (score 2):

### Implementation of TextTrackList

Please refer to this URL first if you did not read.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextTrackList

It metioned that

**addtrack**

> Fired when a new text track has been **added to the media element**.

**removetrack**

> Fired when a new text track has been **removed from the media element**.

As you can see from the above, `addtrack` and `removetrack` events are **dependent on HTMLMediaElement**.

### Remove track with DOM element .removeChild()

```
<!-- HTML -->
<video src="foo.ogv">
    <track kind="subtitles" label="English subtitles" src="subtitles_en.vtt" srclang="en" default>
    </track>
    <track kind="subtitles" label="Deutsche Untertitel" src="subtitles_de.vtt" srclang="de">
    </track>
</video>
```

videoElement.textTracks console output

```
var videoElement = document.querySelector("video");
console.log(videoElement.textTracks);
```

```
//output
TextTrackList {0: TextTrack, 1: TextTrack, length: 2, onchange: null, onaddtrack: null, onremovetrack: null}
0: TextTrack {kind: "subtitles", label: "English subtitles", language: "en", id: "", mode: "showing", …}
1: TextTrack {kind: "subtitles", label: "Deutsche Untertitel", language: "de", id: "", mode: "disabled", …}
length: 2
```

```
videoElement.textTracks.onremovetrack = function(event){
    console.log('DOM removed',event)
    console.log(videoElement.textTracks)
}
var tracks = videoElement.querySelectorAll('track')
videoElement.removeChild(tracks[0])

//output
DOM removed TrackEvent {isTrusted: true, track: TextTrack, type: "removetrack", target: TextTrackList, currentTarget: TextTrackList, …}
TextTrackList {0: TextTrack, 1: TextTrack, length: 1,...}
0: TextTrack {kind: "subtitles", label: "Deutsche Untertitel", language: "de", id: "", mode: "disabled", …}
```

**Disable Track**

```
videoElement.textTracks[0].mode = "disabled"; // Disable English
videoElement.textTracks[1].mode = "showing";  // Enable Deutsche
```

**addTextTrack & removeTextTrack**

`addTextTrack` method will not create `track element` to HTMLMediaElement, thus you need to create and append `track element` manually if you need to remove a track using DOM element.

There is no `removeTextTrack` method at the moment. If you need `removeTextTrack` please visit the following as @Endless mentioned from the above comment. https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1921

Comment: Please consider editing your answer and **delete** the "Remove Track" part as it might cause damage! `<track>` is **not** the only type of children `<video>` has, for example [see this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_track.asp), plus `textTracks` might even match `<track>`s (if JS was used to create `textTracks` directly).

Comment: @LWC , thank you for the suggestion. I modified the above to use `videoElement.querySelectorAll('track')` to avoid affect other tags.

Comment: Thanks! But my other line missed the word "not" ("might not") - textTracks might not even match <track>s (if JS was used to create textTracks directly), so how to deal with that?

Comment: @LWC , would you be able to provide a reproducible code of your issue?

Comment: Guess you can just try https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_video_addtexttrack.asp while **also** already using HTML <track>s.

Comment: @LWC, there is no `removeTextTrack` method as you know. When you use `addTextTrack` , you may add `track` element to DOM as well.

Comment: Not having `removeTextTrack` is exactly why we're all here. It's a complex situation. But none of the scripts I saw online (not even MDN/W3) bothered to add HTML `<track>` when they used `addTextTrack`.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using javascript and the VideoJS library (tested and works with 1 or more tracks):

Get the media player object in the DOM using some sort of selector, then get all it's tracks, then remove them one by one by iterating through the array in reverse order.

```
var player = videojs(document.getElementById(playerId));
var tracks = player.remoteTextTracks();
var numTracks = tracks.length;
for(var i = numTracks - 1; i >=0 ; i--) {
    player.removeRemoteTextTrack(tracks[i]);
}
```

Comment: "remoteTextTracks is not a function"

Comment: This solution uses videojs so you need to include videojs libraries.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to get this to work with video.js 8.x, though it worked well in 7.x versions of video.js. I get "Property 'remoteTextTracks' does not exist on type 'Player'. Did you mean 'addRemoteTextTrack'?" error.

Answer (score 1):

```js
//best way to do this thing
//disable The Old Subtitles From The Dom
var tracks = document.querySelector("video").textTracks;
var numTracks = tracks.length;
for (var i = numTracks - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  document.querySelector("video").textTracks[i].mode = "disabled";
```

```html
<video>
    <track>
    <track>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Much more verbose, but you could use the DOM API. Most of the work is to find the correspondence between the DOM TrackElement and the TextTrack from `video.textTracks`.

A track added with `video.addTextTrack` strangely do not get added to the DOM.

#### Add track

```
const textTracksBefore = Array.from(videoElement.textTracks);
const trackElement = document.createElement('track');
trackElement.kind = 'subtitles';
trackElement.label = PlayerShakaTextDisplayer.TextTrackLabel_;
trackElement.srclang = language;
videoElement.appendChild(trackElement);
this.trackElement_ = trackElement;
const textTracksAfter = Array.from(videoElement.textTracks);
const newTracks = textTracksAfter.filter(x => !textTracksBefore.includes(x));
this.textTrack_ = newTracks[0];
```

#### Remove track

```
this.videoElement.removeChild(this.trackElement_);
this.trackElement_ = null;
this.textTrack_ = null;
```